# Global cache with specific object attributes as input in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, caching, global, memoization

In my attempt to achieve a class level cache decorator, I have stumbled across the `ring` library which is able to save a function's inputs an outputs globally. It basically allows me to achieve the following behavior, given the `class` definition of `Calculate` as below:

```
import ring

class Calculate:

    @ring.dict({})
    def sum(self, a, b):
       print('actually calculating')
       sum = a + b
       return sum
```

this is the behavior I am trying to achieve with `Calculate`

```
>>> calculate = Calculate()
>>> calcualte.sum(5,7)
actually calculating
12

>>> different_calculate = Calculate()
>>> different_calculate.sum(5,7)
12    #this outputs 12 straight from the cache from first calculate. 
#Note that even if 'different_calculate' and 'calculate' are different instantiations of 'Calculate', the cache works at a class level. Therefore the sum is not actually REcalculated.
```

Now, I need to achieve the same behavior with `sum`, this time being a property. The issue that I am facing here is that in a `@property` `def` takes as argument `self`. Therefore, when trying to cache as in the previous example it will not work, because the input is no longer `num1` and `num2`, but `self`, which changes with every instantiation. Therefore it will never pull from cache on a different class instantiation, as self always changes with every instantiation. See below:

```
import ring

class Calculate:
   def __init__(self, num1, num2):
      self.num1 = num1
      self.num2 = num2

    @ring.dict({})
    @property
    def sum(self):
       print('actually calculating')
       sum = num1 + num2
       return sum

>>> calculate = Calculate()
>>> calcualte.sum(5,7)
actually calculating
12

>>> different_calculate = Calculate()
>>> different_calculate.sum(5,7)
actually calculating
12
```

To solve this problem, I somehow have to tell the cache library not to look at `self`  as input, but at `self.num1`, `self.num2`. The code will then nee to be something like this:

```
   @ring.dict(self.num1, self.num2)  # <--- this does not exist
    @property
    def sum(self):
       print('actually calculating')
       sum = num1 + num2
       return sum
```

Is there any way I can do this with `ring`, or any other python cache library for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after getting some inspiration from [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php), I ended up just creating my own memoization function, as so:

```
memo = {}

def memoize(*attrs):  
    def wrapper(f):  
        def helper(obj):
            key = tuple([getattr(obj,attr) for attr in attrs])
            if key not in memo:            
                memo[key] = f(obj)
            return memo[key]
        return helper
    return wrapper




class Calculate:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    @property
    @memoize('num1', 'num2')  
    def sum(self):
        print('actually calculating')
        sum = self.num1 + self.num2
        return sum


>>> calculate = Calculate(6,9)
>>> calculate.sum
actually calculating
15

>>> another_calculate = Calculate(6,9)
>>> another_calculate.sum
15
```